# Which database to use xamarin android

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.android

Developing a xamarin android app. This app needs to have an external database.
I don't have any experience with these kind of databases/connections.

The database contains data that changes from time to time. And the app only needs to read the data so not create/update/delete.
The database contains no sensitive data so an API would be overkill.

SQLite is no option because it's a local database. 
What other simple options do i have left?

Comment: how can you connect an external database without API? I assume you mean like cloud database by external database.

Comment: You can connect directly to a SQL Server Database, without the need of an API. But this is not recommended. You really should use a Web API to send/retrieve data from a database.

Comment: Thanks both of you. @GregoryP How can i achieve this? Because i cant find any link on the net that explains this. From creating a mysql database to connecting it

Comment: What kind of data do you need to store in the database?

Comment: @GregoryP Only room numbers of a building. So no sensitive data

Comment: Ok. I'll provide a solution based on what you told me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Urban information, I think this is the best approach.

This is a solution for those who needs to store simple information in a database (can be accessed everywhere since it'll have a url by azure: yoururl.azurewebsites.net)

Since you'll only store room numbers (no sensitive data) and probably not too many records, you can use **Easy Tables** from **Azure Mobile Apps**.

---

#### 1. Create an account on Azure

First of all, create an account on azure and you'll get $25 credit every month for one year. That $25 should do to store/retrieve your data from Azure. Yes, it's not free to consume Azure services.

Use this link: [Azure Subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/vs-dev-essentials/)

#### 2. Setup Easy Tables with Azure Mobile Apps

After you create your account on Azure, follow the steps in this article to create an Mobile App, configure Easy tables and store/retrieve data from Azure Services.

Article: [Getting Started](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/)

---

This is the easiest way to store data in a database without creating any Web API or any database on your own.

Just remember: Easy Tables is recommended to store simple data: some numbers, user sessions, configuration strings and things like that. If you want to store real data (large amount of it), you should check about Web API and REST services.